# How to find ng-repeater that contains a specific text with selenium and Python

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium

I have a angular web app that i want to test with selenium & python
the html file goes like that:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div ng-repeat="address in addresses">
       bla
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="address in addresses">
       dodo
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div ng-repeat="address in addresses">
       foo
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="address in addresses">
       didi
    </div>

</div>
```

with selenium and python i want to find all elements that are in the item in items repeater but ONLY if  contains a specific text (e.g. bla)

that means that i want to get all items in the first repeater and not in the second repeater by text that appears on the web page

I have tried something like that

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[ng-repeat='item in items'] and (contains(text(), 'bla'))")
```

my error:

```
invalidSelectorException
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[ng-repeat='item in items'] and (contains(text(), 'bla'))")
```

try:

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@ng-repeat='item in items' and contains(., 'bla')]")
```

what I did there was change the position of the closing square bracket and added a `@` at the start of ng-repeat - syntax for attribute checking, changed `find_element_by_xpath` to `find_elements_by_xpath` and finally changed the `text()` to a `.` (a single dot). That's usually better when you have multiple texts in different child nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I would try below xpath-

```
//div[@ng-repeat='item in items']/div[@ng-repeat='address in addresses' and contains (text(),'bla')]
```

For html-

```
<div>
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div ng-repeat="address in addresses">
       bla
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="address in addresses">
       dodo
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div ng-repeat="address in addresses">
       foo
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="address in addresses">
       didi
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

See demo test at [HERE](http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery/65291c58799769e8f3cc5ce25823b5bb).